# imacros for facebook is not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, imacros

I have boosted a post on my fan page page. When I click on the likes, it shows, "**Invite People Who Like This Post to Like Your Page**" .

I am writing a IMACROS Script so I can easily invite users to my fanpage automatically without clicking on invite button every single time.

[image: Invite People Who Like This Post to Like Your Page]

I have done something like this but it is not working. I need somebody to fix it:

```
**VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/browse/likes?id=488030621342505&actorid=479841822161385
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=3 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=4 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=5 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=6 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=7 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=8 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=9 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=10 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=11 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=12 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=13 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=14 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=15 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=16 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=17 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=18 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=19 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=20 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=21 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
TAG POS=22 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite**
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Invite
```

Try it like this. If it doesn't work then check the HTML code of Invite button. Paste it here and you will get the iMacros command for invite button.